# How to show a warning sign while building a form in html5?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, required

I have a form as shown below in which I placing an `alt text` which will display on the webpage.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Alt <input type="text" name="e1_alt" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The form here will not save because I have used the required field in it. What I want to achieve is that a warning sign should be displayed if it is empty but it should not stop the user from saving it.

**Problem Statement:** I am wondering what changes I should make in the HTML code above or **JavaScript code** I need to add so that a warning sign should be displayed if it is empty 
but it should not stop the user from saving it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do it purely in HTML. Javascript would need to handle the validation. HTML5 forms will not submit if you have a required field empty, since that's how the browsers handle them. You could add novalidate to the form as an attribute, but you'd still need to have some javascript to handle showing the 'warning sign

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettgaynor/v4hsrbg7/10/) to show you how you might go about using JS to show the warning:

```
$('[name="e1_alt"]').blur(function(e) {
    var value = $(e.currentTarget).val();

  if (value.length === 0) {
    $('.error').show();
  }
});
```